# Define a structure $M\neq N$ such that $M \vDash \forall x(y < x \to \exists z(z < y))$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Let $N$ be the natural numbers with the standard order: $N = (N, <)$.

Define a structure $M \neq N$ such that $M \vDash \forall x(y < x \to \exists z(z < y))$

Not entirely sure what the above exercise is asking for due to the "Define a structure $M \neq N$".
Does it want me to define a structure where $M$ where $M$ (meaning $x, y$ and $z$) is not a natural number? From what I can tell the statement is not true for natural numbers regardless since if $x =2$, $y =1$ and $0$ is not a natural number.

Comment: I guess the *underlying set* of $M'$ has to be equal with the set of natural numbers. In that case, you can just interpret the relation $x<y$ to mean '$x$ is *bigger* than $y$'

Comment: What does it entail that M ̸= N? Does that mean that with my definitions M cannot be the natural numbers in my definition?

Comment: It refers to *structures*=domain + "relations". In this case, the domain of $M$ will be made of the usual numbers, but the binary predicate symbol $<$ will be interpreted in a different way from usual "less than".

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $\forall x(y < x \rightarrow\exists z(z < y))$ is still an open formula with the variable $y$ free. Thus, $y$ assumes a *parametric* presence. For instance,  if $y$ is given a fixed interpretation as $2$, we get

$$\forall x(2 < x \rightarrow\exists z(z < 2))$$

We consider the equivalent formula $\exists x(2 < x) \rightarrow\exists z(z < 2))$ and immediately see that the consequent is always satisfied. Hence, if $y$ could be assigned uniformly any value other than $0$ (most, if not all, of the widely known books in model theory count $0$ as a natural number), the structure $N$ would fulfil the task. For each such value of $y$, we would have a set of formulas satisfied by $N$. To make the matter more solid, I adapt the following definitions from Chang and Keisler's *[Model Theory](https://books.google.com.tr/books/about/Model_Theory.html?id=sRi0AAAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y)* (3rd edition, p. 77) to the present case:

Let $\Phi$ be a set of formulas of a first-order language $\mathcal{L}$ in the free individual variable $y$ such that every formula $\phi(y)$ in $\Phi$ contains at most the variable $y$ free. Then, we denote the statement that $a\in$ M (the domain of $M$) satisfies $\phi$ in $\Phi$ by

$$M\models\phi(a)$$

and the statement that $a\in$ M satisfies every $\phi$ in $\Phi$ by

$$M\models\Phi(a)$$

The exercise asks us to set out a new structure distinct than $N$ to accomplish this idea. A straightforward method is to expand the signature of the structure $N$ with a new constant symbol $y$ (for the sake of simplicity; also delete it from the list of variables against collisions) and fix its interpretation to the constant, say, $1$ in the domain. Hence, we obtain

$$M = \langle\mathbb{N}, <, y\rangle$$

which fulfils the requirements of the question. Sure, other methods are possible as stated in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any requirement that the universe of $M$ has to be all natural numbers, and we're assuming you mean that $M$ is supposed to be a **sub**structure of $(\mathbb{N}, <)$, not just any structure distinct from it.

Note that the formula is equivalent to: $(\exists x)\,y < x \to (\exists z)\,z < y$, which says "if there are elements greater than $y$, then there are elements less than $y$".

Given these assumptions and observations, you can just take $M = (\{1\}, <)$, which satisfies the formula.

Aside: $0$ **is** a natural number. Some authors define $\mathbb{N}$ to begin with $1$, but this is wrong-headed :) For one thing, that structure is not a model of Peano arithmetic.